# MUI: Can one use `multiple` with `defaultValue` for uncontrolled Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using MUI with React Hooks and TypeScript. I have a reusable component, `Dropdown` in my application which uses the `Autocomplete` component:

```
export interface DropdownInterface {
  id: string,
  value?: string | string[] | null,
  defaultValue?: string | string[] | null,
  options: string[],
  onChange: (e: any, newValue: any) => void,
  renderInput: (params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => React.ReactNode,
  isMultiSelect?: boolean,
}

const Dropdown = ( { id, value, defaultValue, options, onChange, renderInput, isMultiSelect, 
}: DropdownInterface): JSX.Element => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id={id}
      value={value}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      options={options}
      multiple={isMultiSelect}
      onChange={onChange}
      renderInput={renderInput}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, currentValue) => option === currentValue}
      filterSelectedOptions
      fullWidth
      open={open}
      onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
      onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
    />
  );
};
```

Note the presence of both `value` for controlled instances and `defaultValue` for uncontrolled.

I am able to use this component successfully as a controlled component for both single-select and multi-select (hence the `isMultiSelect` prop above) in a generic form dialog. I am attempting to refactor my form dialog to uncontrolled components. I have done so by wrapping sections of my form dialog in an HTML form tag:

```
          <form noValidate onSubmit={(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
            console.log(formData.entries());
            const fieldValues = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
            console.log(fieldValues);
            handleSubmit(fieldValues);
          }}>
            <DialogContent>
                {content}
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
              <Button onClick={closeDialog}>
                {actionLabels.cancel}
              </Button>
              <Button type="submit">
                {actionLabels.submit}
            </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          </form>
```

`Autocomplete` as uncontrolled returns a string for single-select, and so my custom component worked as expected, with `Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())` returning a fieldValue as expected. This instance of my custom component, however, did not:

```
        <Dropdown 
          id="roles"
          isMultiSelect={true}

          defaultValue={user ? user.roles.map(r => r.name) : []}
          options={roles.map(r => r.name)}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              {...params}
              name="roles"
              label="Roles"
              margin="dense"
            />
          )}
        />
```

When I submitted the form, I received `roles: ''` in the object returned by `Object.fromEntries(formData.entries())`. From the docs, when `multiple` is true on `Autocomplete`, `value` will be an array. How does `multiple` affect `defaultValue`, and can `multiple` be true on uncontrolled instances of `Autocomplete`?